# Combining time series data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and like to add a column to the first one with volume information from the second one. The first dataframe should have a volume column with the sum of the volume from the second dataframe determined between the index rows of the first dataframe.
Can someone point me in the right direction please? So 507 in the example would be 260+61+186 from the other dataframe(*) between the corresponding times.

Thanks!!

```
dataframe 1

                    adjclose   
datetime    
2022-10-20 02:55:00 30492.0    
2022-10-20 03:10:00 30402.0    
2022-10-20 03:20:00 30457.0    
2022-10-20 03:45:00 30376.0
2022-10-20 04:05:00 30425.0
2022-10-20 04:10:00 30373.0
2022-10-20 04:45:00 30436.0
2022-10-20 04:55:00 30401.0
2022-10-20 05:25:00 30437.0

Dataframe 2

                    volume
datetime    
2022-10-20 02:40:00 119.0
2022-10-20 02:45:00 210.0
2022-10-20 02:50:00 179.0
2022-10-20 02:55:00 260.0*
2022-10-20 03:00:00 61.0*
2022-10-20 03:05:00 186.0*
2022-10-20 03:10:00 204.0
2022-10-20 03:15:00 333.0
2022-10-20 03:20:00 122.0
2022-10-20 03:25:00 75.0

Desired result

                    adjclose volume
datetime    
2022-10-20 02:35:00 30433.0   507
2022-10-20 02:55:00 30492.0   etc
2022-10-20 03:10:00 30402.0   etc
2022-10-20 03:20:00 30457.0
2022-10-20 03:45:00 30376.0
2022-10-20 04:05:00 30425.0
2022-10-20 04:10:00 30373.0
2022-10-20 04:45:00 30436.0
2022-10-20 04:55:00 30401.0
2022-10-20 05:25:00 30437.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)

s = pd.Series(range(len(df1)), index=df1.index, name='id')

df1['volume'] = s.map(
    pd.merge_asof(df2, df1.assign(id=s)['id'],
                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
   .groupby('id').sum()['volume']
)
```

*NB. ensure df1 and df2's indexes are sorted in ascending order.*

output:

```
                     adjclose  volume
datetime                             
2022-10-20 02:55:00   30492.0   507.0
2022-10-20 03:10:00   30402.0   537.0
2022-10-20 03:20:00   30457.0   197.0
2022-10-20 03:45:00   30376.0     NaN
2022-10-20 04:05:00   30425.0     NaN
2022-10-20 04:10:00   30373.0     NaN
2022-10-20 04:45:00   30436.0     NaN
2022-10-20 04:55:00   30401.0     NaN
2022-10-20 05:25:00   30437.0     NaN
```

Comment: Python is beautiful... merge_asof: Merge by key distance. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Yes, this is a great function ;)

Comment: What about merging different columns? Is there a one command way to do add the sum of volume and for example the last of close (or the first of open, the max of high, the min of low)?

Answer (score 0):

You ca use pandas DataFrame.join

> Join columns of another DataFrame.
>
> Join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key column.
> Efficiently join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once by
> passing a list.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is the documentation with some examples